# android - long running process in the background thread (IntentService)

Tags: android

I am working on an android that needs to connect to multiple bluetooth to receive data. So if the mobile device is within the range of these bluetooth, it will be connected to them. If not, it will be on pause and be reconnected to them when the mobile device is near the bluetooth.

So far, connect/disconnect/reconnect has been working pretty well.

I separated the long running process from the UI part. I am running the bluetooth connect/disconnect/reconnect in the intentservice so that even though the app is not used by a user, the business logic related to bluetooth data should be up and running all the time (if the battery is good).

Here is the step.
1. a user activates the bluetooth connection (for now three bluetooth socket connections) in the activity. 
2. The activity starts the intentservice.
3. The intentservice creates a separate thread which handles connect/disconnect/reconnect logic in the background.
4. Another thread which handles bluetooth data analysis and does some business logic is created from the intentservice.

So the thread handling connect/disconnect/reconnect should be up and running all the time as long as the battery life is good.

But the weird thing that I noticed is that the thread dies at some point (not sure when). I left my phone (plugged into the power) near the bluetooth devices over the night, which means that the phone was connected to the bluetooth the whole time.

But when I checked the connection thread next day in the eclipse debug mode, it died. It wasn't there, and I saw the IntentService thread suspended.

Does android platform kill the IntentService after several hours?

I am sorry for the lengthy explanation without source code. Code is complicated, but I am trying to figure out why the thread died. It's hard to find the log too, so I can't even tell what happened.

Is there any limitation on the IntentService process time?

I'd appreciated if there is any blog/resource/hint.

Comment: `IntentService` dies after  the execution of its `onHandleIntent` method.

Comment: I have a thread join method there, so the flow is still inside onHandleIntent. And there is ping msg between the mobile device and the bluetooth devices every 5 minutes as well.